# How to add multiple ractive objects on one page?

Tags: ractivejs

I am new to Ractive JS.I want to know that How to create multiple ractive objects for individual template?

Thanks In Advance 
Samir Kahar

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use a [component](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/components). See also the [extending Ractive](http://learn.ractivejs.org/extending-ractive/1) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You just create multiple Ractive instances.  Here's about the simplest possible ractive template used twice on the same page with different data:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>

<script type="text/ractive" id="sampleTemplate">
    Hello, {{name}}.
</script>

<script>
    var ractive1 = new Ractive({
        el: '#div1',
        template: '#sampleTemplate',
        data: { name: 'World' }
    });
    var ractive2 = new Ractive({
        el: '#div2',
        template: '#sampleTemplate',
        data: { name: 'World 2' }
    });
</script>
```